# Dynamic/Filterable Org Chart diagonalNetwork Visualization in R

Tags: r, networkd3

My code, using the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) and `data.tree` packages, produces a static organizational chart/network tree that shows the relationship between a fictitious set of employees and their supervisors.

**I would like to make the nodes filterable to where I can start at the topmost level and filter downward.** This would make the presentation of the visualization much more impactful and valuable. I am unable to find any helpful resources or packages that will allow me to do this within R.

```
library('data.tree')
library('networkD3')
census <- data.frame("Employee"=c("Bill","James","Amy","Jen","Henry"),
                     "Supervisor"=c("Jen","Jen","Steve","Amy","Amy"))

orgChart <- FromDataFrameNetwork(census)
orgChartList <- ToListExplicit(orgChart,unname=T)
orgChart_plot <- diagonalNetwork(orgChartList,nodeColour="orange",fontSize=14,height=200,width=400,linkColour="black")
orgChart_plot
```

[image: org chart]

Comment: This is currently not possible with `networkD3`, but a development version is in the works with interactive, collapsible tree networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current (18.06.2017) dev version of [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) on GitHub has a new `treeNetwork` function that creates highly customizable, collapsible tree plots. You can install the dev version with...

```
devtools::install_github('christophergandrud/networkD3')
```

Comment: I continue to receive the following message when the `treeNetwork` function hits the intial data conversion line:

code line: `# convert to the native data format 
33   data <- as_treenetdf(data, ...)`

error: `Error: 'as.tibble' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tibble'`

Comment: Please open a new issue with a reproducible example at https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues

Comment: What version of tibble do you have installed? You may need to update.

Comment: I am on version 1.2. I tried an update and am still receiving the same error.